# Color in BarPlots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to recreate this graph produced by Tableau using `ggplot2`. I've gotten far enough but I can't seem to figure out how to add color (whose intensity is proportional to the amount of profit).

The dataset is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bcwgruejum1tg1j/CoffeeChain.csv)

Here's the plot I want to replicate

[image: ggplot image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wcu780m72a85lvi/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-11%20at%209.05.49%20PM.png

Here's my code so far:

```
    ggplot(coffee,aes(x=Product,weight=Sales))
    +geom_bar()+facet_grid(Market~Product.Type,scales="free_x",space="free")
    +ylab("Sales")+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))
```

Comment: You can add a `+ theme_bw() + theme(strip.background=element_blank()) + theme(panel.grid=element_blank())` to either solution to remove the grid & gray facet strip background to more closely match your Tableau chart. You can also use `gsub` to stick a `\n` after certain words to ensure they wrap (i.e. "Decaf Espresso" is a whole line in the ggplot2 examples whereas it's split in the Tableau one). That wld avoid the needing to turn one's head to read the labels in the ggplot solutions below: `coffee$Product <- gsub(" (Cream|Espresso)", "\n\\1", coffee$Product)` (do that before the aggregation)

Comment: @hrbrmstr thats useful info. I was wondering about the 90 degree labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the aggregate function.

```
library(ggplot2)

coffee <- read.csv('CoffeeChain.csv')
agg <- aggregate(cbind(Profit, Sales) ~ Product+Market+Product.Type, data=coffee, FUN=sum)

ggplot(agg, aes(x=Product, weight=Sales, fill=Profit), stat="identity") +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#F37767", "#9FC08D", "#6BA862", "#2B893E", "#036227")) +
  facet_grid(Market~Product.Type, scales="free_x", space="free") +
    ylab("Sales") +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))
```

[image: Pretty pic]

Comment: Nice use `c("#F37767", "#9FC08D", "#6BA862", "#2B893E", "#036227")` for colors and it matches the OP's

Comment: Your method is alot simpler then the one I used. It should be the answer I think.

Comment: Beautiful too. Thank you Cole.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best way to do it:

```
require(ggplot2)
aggProfit <- ave(coffee$Profit, coffee$Product.Type, coffee$Product, coffee$Market, FUN=sum)
coffee$Breaks<- cut(aggProfit, c(seq(-8000, 25000, 5000), max(aggSales)), dig.lab = 10)
appcolors <- c("#F37767", "#9FC08D", "#6BA862", "#2B893E", "#036227")
gg <- ggplot(coffee,aes(x=Product,weight=Sales, fill = Breaks))+
  geom_bar()+facet_grid(Market~Product.Type,scales="free_x",space="free")+
  ylab("Sales")+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colorRampPalette(appcolors)( length(levels(coffee$Breaks)) ))
plot(gg)
```

To get the colors `c("#F37767", "#9FC08D", "#6BA862", "#2B893E", "#036227")` I used the [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/firefox/) plugin.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic JD. Thank you very very much. It is clear to me that I could never have figured this one out.